# Using cell value as reference to sheet in formulas

Tags: date, google-sheets, importrange

I have a spreadsheet with three sheets. Two are called `2012` and `2011` and have a bunch of similar data. The last sheet does comparisons between the data.

To be able to choose year, I'm using a cell (D1) where I can I can write either `2011` or `2012`. The formulas then use the INDIRECT function to include this cell as part of the reference.

```
INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!F:F")
```

This is not a pretty solution and makes the formula quite long and complex.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER( INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!M:M") ;  (INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!B:B")=$A4)+(INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!B:B")=$A5)+(INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!B:B")=$A6)+(INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!B:B")=$A7)+(INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!B:B")=$A8); MONTH(INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!D:D"))=$B$1 ; INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!F:F")=D$3));0)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

I've tried to create a separate spreadsheet for the calculations sheet and importing (IMPORTRANGE) the data from the two sheets together on one sheet with VMERGE (custom function from the script gallery) but there is quite a lot of of data in these two sheets and the import takes a long time. Any changes (like changing year) also take a long time to recalculate.

Comment: if, as you mentioned, there is "quite a lot of data in these two sheets" I would think custom functions are probably not the most effective approach since they are quite slow... Have you tried to figure out if your data comparisons could be made in javaScript inside a function using data arrays ?

Comment: As my custom function does not handle any data-manipulations (as far as I know), I thought that the speed of the custom function would be acceptable. In all essence it only provides the INDIRECT formula with the variable CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!A:A", but in a neater way (for better readability). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The custom function _is_ actually having an impact on speed. Thanks for the tip. I've solved it with DSUM as hinted by the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database functions tend to be cleaner when doing this kind of thing.

https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1368827

Database functions take a while to learn, but they are powerful.

Or

You could put INDIRECT(CHAR(39)&$D$1&CHAR(39)&"!B:B") in a cell on its own.

Comment: With a little work and change, DSUM did solve my particular problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have two years of information where the schema is identical (column C has the same type of information on both sheets).  Also, I'm assuming that column B tracks the year.

If so, consider holding all of your information on one sheet and and use the spreadsheet function "QUERY" to create views.

For instance, this formula returns all the cells between A1:E from a sheet named "DataSheet" where the values in column B = 2010.

=QUERY(DataSheet!A1:E; "SELECT * WHERE B = 2010";1)

Sometimes there is a really good reason to have the data stored on two sheets.  If so, use one of the vMerge functions in the script gallery to assemble a working sheet. Then create views and reports from the working sheet.

```
function VMerge() {
  var maxw=l=0;
  var minw=Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var al=arguments.length ;
  for( i=0 ; i<al ; i++){
    if( arguments[i].constructor == Array )l =arguments[i][0].length ;
    else if (arguments[i].length!=0) l = 1 ;  // literal values count as array with a width of one cell, empty cells are ignored!
    maxw=l>maxw?l:maxw;
    minw=l<minw?l:minw;
  }
  if( maxw==minw) { /* when largest width equals smallest width all are equal */
    var s = new Array();
    for( i=0 ; i<al ; i++){
      if( arguments[i].constructor == Array ) s = s.concat( arguments[i].slice() )
      else if (arguments[i].length!=0) s = s.concat( [[arguments[i]]] )  
    }
  if ( s.length == 0 ) return null ; else return s        //s     
  }
  else return "#N/A: All data ranges must be of equal width!"      
}
```

Hope this helps.