# Change formula in link

Tags: excel-formula

I want to change this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,[Book3]Aug!$E$7:$F$13,2,0)
```

by changing Aug to Sep by referring a cell value which has Aug,Sep,Oct i.e if Cell A1 has Aug.  Now if I change cell A1 value as Sep, the formula should become:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,[Book3]Sep!$E$7:$F$13,2,0)
```

Comment: If you only want to switch between Aug & Sep then and if() to pick either formula will work or you could use indirect().

Comment: Can u show me how?\

Comment: Both methods exist on here so have a search.

Comment: @SolarMike please do share the link of existing answer, so that he can easily get it and understand, instead of spending time to search exact one.

Comment: @Regiz searching is the whole point of the Stack format, I have found many answers to my own questions by searching prior to posting. This reduces the number of posts that have to be closed as duplicate.

Comment: For indirect() have a look at this, as but one example, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11069915/4961700

Comment: Yaa! got your point @SolarMike !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no sample snap in your question. some how i predicted and posting the answer based on you written formula and question that you asked.

If this is not your expected answer, please let me know and share your data snaps to work on it.

**Here you go for an Example of your requirement:**

**Book3**: which is having data in monthly wise sheet.

**Test_If and Vlookup** : which is worked with formula as you said.
**In Test Book** the cell **B3** contains formula like below which is taking reference of **A1** for if and **A3** for `Vlookup()` reference and then taking array from **Book3**
to get 2 columns value.

Here i used Two method of formulas one is directly entering column number to get matched data and Used `Match()` function for instead of entering column number.

**Formula Used by entering column number In `B3` and Copied to All**

```
=IF($A$1="Aug",VLOOKUP($A3,[Book3.xlsx]Aug!$A:$D,2,0),IF($A$1="Sep",VLOOKUP($A3,[Book3.xlsx]Sep!$A:$D,2,0),VLOOKUP($A3,[Book3.xlsx]Oct!$A:$D,2,0)))
```

**If Want With Match Function instead of entering column number which is used in `B3` and Copied to All**

```
=IF($A$1="Aug",VLOOKUP($A3,[Book3.xlsx]Aug!$A:$D,MATCH(B$2,[Book3.xlsx]Aug!$A$1:$D$1,0),0),IF($A$1="Sep",VLOOKUP($A3,[Book3.xlsx]Sep!$A:$D,MATCH(B$2,[Book3.xlsx]Sep!$A$1:$D$1,0),0),VLOOKUP($A3,[Book3.xlsx]Oct!$A:$D,MATCH(B$2,[Book3.xlsx]Oct!$A$1:$D$1,0),0)))
```

> After used this Formula, you can modify the A1 Cell value as Sep or Oct in Test
>   workbook, the formula will be worked based on True condition, for the reason only used IF condition and which have been commented by @solar

**Please refer the below snaps to understand more.**

**Book 3** Where the complete data is available in monthly wise sheet.

[image]

**Test_`If` and `V lookup`** Excel Book which is worked with formula.

[image]

If need any more knowledge about if and Vlookup please refer below link.
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/02/07/if-vlookup-excel/